# How to draw cylinder in y or x axis in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, cylindrical

I just want to draw a cylinder in opengl. I found lots of samples but all of them draws cylinders in z axis. I want them be in x or y axis. How can i do this. The code below is the code draw the cylinder in z direction and i dont want it

```
  GLUquadricObj *quadratic;
  quadratic = gluNewQuadric();
  gluCylinder(quadratic,0.1f,0.1f,3.0f,32,32);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `glRotate(angle, x, y, z)` to rotate your coordinate system:

```
GLUquadricObj *quadratic;
quadratic = gluNewQuadric();
glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
gluCylinder(quadratic,0.1f,0.1f,3.0f,32,32);
```

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml

Answer (score 4):

On every render use `glPushMatrix` `glRotatef` draw the cylinder and finish your drawing with `glPopMatrix`.

Ex.: `glRotatef(yRotationAngle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Rotate your object around the y axis on yRotationAngle radians`

Ex.: `OnRender()` function example

```
void OnRender() {
  glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Clear the background
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Clear the colour buffer
  glLoadIdentity(); // Load the Identity Matrix to reset our drawing locations

  glRotatef(yRotationAngle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Rotate our object around the y axis on yRotationAngle radians

  // here *render* your cylinder (create and delete it in the other place. Not while rendering)
  gluCylinder(quadratic,0.1f,0.1f,3.0f,32,32);

  glFlush(); // Flush the OpenGL buffers to the window  
}
```